# Gack Id Error ID: 2058118216-46834 (-1126405779) for setting Visualforce Page Security Settings

Tags: visualforce, security, gack

When I tried to create a new Visualforce Page on a new scratch org, and grant access to all profiles, I received an error Error ID: 2058118216-46834 (-1126405779).
Why does it happen? What is the underlying stack trace id?

Answer (score 1):

I have opened a Salesforce support case and the following information I got from the Salesforce Support specialist

`````
`00D1F000000s753`0051F00000sfRlK``2058118216-46834`-1126405779`/ex/UnhandledException.jsp````SEVERE``common.udd.object.EntityObject`saveHook_SqlExceptionRemapper`common.exception.SqlDupValOnIndexException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORE.AKSETUP_ENTITY_ACCESS) violated
ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.UDDDMLSETUPENTITYACCESS", line 78
ORA-06512: at line 1


{call UddDmlSetupEntityAccess.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?)}

{call UddDmlSetupEntityAccess.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?)} at ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORE.AKSETUP_ENTITY_ACCESS) violated

SourceClassName: common.udd.object.EntityObject
SourceMethodName: saveHook_SqlExceptionRemapper
OrganizationId: 00D1F000000s753
UserId: 0051F00000sfRlK
Subject: common.exception.SqlDupValOnIndexException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORE.AKSETUP_ENTITY_ACCESS) violated
ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.UDDDMLSETUPENTITYACCESS", line 78
ORA-06512: at line 1


{call UddDmlSetupEntityAccess.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?)}

{call UddDmlSetupEntityAccess.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?)}
ExtendedMessage: null


java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORE.AKSETUP_ENTITY_ACCESS) violated
ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.UDDDMLSETUPENTITYACCESS", line 78
ORA-06512: at line 1

Cause1-SQLState: 23000
Cause1-SQLVendorCode: 1
Cause1-StackTrace:
... 239 shared with parent

Cause2: Error : 1, Position : 0, Sql = BEGIN UddDmlSetupEntityAccess.bulk_insert_detail(:1 ,:2 ,:3 ,:4 ); END;, OriginalSql = {call UddDmlSetupEntityAccess.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?)}, Error Msg = ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORE.AKSETUP_ENTITY_ACCESS) violated
ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.UDDDMLSETUPENTITYACCESS", line 78
ORA-06512: at line 1
`````

I wasn't able to reproduce this error again.

My gut feeling was that it is somehow related with 'Authenticated Profile' duplicated profile in the org, however, still I couldn't reproduce the problem.

---

Salesforce support representative also provided some more information which actually didn't help me but maybe would be helpful for someone reading this

> A unique constraint violation occurs when an UPDATE or INSERT
> statement attempts to insert a record with a key that already exists
> in the table. Take a look at the package that is throwing the error.
>
> There are a few solutions to the “ORA-00001 unique constraint
> violated” error:
>
> 1. Change your SQL so that the unique constraint is not violated.
> 2. Change the constraint to allow for duplicate values.
> 3. Drop the constraint from the column.
> 4. Disable the unique constraint.
>
> Could you please refer below article:
> https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000923KIAQ
>
> https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000360253&type=1